# Weird XOR output "X" when simulating

Tags: cryptography, vhdl, xor, modelsim

I am working on a project. I need to use and lfsr in galois mode to produce a bit vector. The bits on the vector need to be xored to to some specific bits on a 256-bit vector. However when i perform the xor operation, i get "X" on the output.
**lfsr:**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.all;

entity lfsrg2 is
  generic(
    RC_sel : integer
  );
  port (
    r_in : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
    d_in : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    outd : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
);
end lfsrg2;

architecture Behavioral of lfsrg2 is

  type RC_help is array (0 to 16) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal R: RC_help;

  begin

  R(0)<= "1111111" & r_in & d_in;

  RC0 : if RC_sel = 0 generate
    loop0: for i in 1 to 16 generate
      R(i)<= R(i-1)(14 downto 0) & "0" when R(i-1)(15)='0' else (R(i-1)(14 downto 0) & "0") xor x"002d";

    end generate loop0;
  end generate RC0;

  RC1 : if RC_sel = 1 generate
    loop1: for i in 1 to 16 generate

      R(i)<= R(i-1)(14 downto 0) & "0" when R(i-1)(15)='0' else (R(i-1)(14 downto 0) & "0") xor x"0053";

    end generate loop1;
  end generate RC1;

  outd<= R(16);

end architecture Behavioral;
```

**TB**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.all;

entity lfsr_tb is
end lfsr_tb;


architecture Behavioral of lfsr_tb is


  signal r_in : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
  signal d_in : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  signal RC0: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal RC1: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal srb_out: std_logic_vector(255 downto 0);
  signal rc_out: std_logic_vector(255 downto 0);

begin
  rc_out <= (others => '0');
  r_in <= "0" & x"A";
  d_in<= "0101";
  srb_out<= x"2e08cd902fe210f626127ecab75b8f151ba92af0269eec2b5bfca95b5f5457f7";
          -- rc_out <= srb_out;
          i_7: entity work.lfsrg2 (Behavioral) generic map (0) port map(r_in, d_in, RC0);
          i_8: entity work.lfsrg2 (Behavioral) generic map (1) port map(r_in, d_in, RC1);

          rc_out(0) <= srb_out(0) xor RC0(0);
          rc_out(16) <= srb_out(16) xor RC0(1);
          rc_out(32) <= srb_out(32) xor RC0(2);
          rc_out(48) <= srb_out(48) xor RC0(3);
          rc_out(64) <= srb_out(64) xor RC0(4);
          rc_out(80) <= srb_out(80) xor RC0(5);
          rc_out(96) <= srb_out(96) xor RC0(6);
          rc_out(112) <= srb_out(112) xor RC0(7);
          rc_out(128) <= srb_out(128) xor RC0(8);
          rc_out(144) <= srb_out(144) xor RC0(9);
          rc_out(160) <= srb_out(160) xor RC0(10);
          rc_out(176) <= srb_out(176) xor RC0(11);
          rc_out(192) <= srb_out(192) xor RC0(12);
          rc_out(208) <= srb_out(208) xor RC0(13);
          rc_out(224) <= srb_out(224) xor RC0(14);
          rc_out(240) <= srb_out(240) xor RC0(15);

          rc_out(8) <= srb_out(8) xor RC1(0);
          rc_out(24) <= srb_out(24) xor RC1(1);
          rc_out(40) <= srb_out(40) xor RC1(2);
          rc_out(56) <= srb_out(56) xor RC1(3);
          rc_out(72) <= srb_out(72) xor RC1(4);
          rc_out(88) <= srb_out(88) xor RC1(5);
          rc_out(104) <= srb_out(104) xor RC1(6);
          rc_out(120) <= srb_out(120) xor RC1(7);
          rc_out(136) <= srb_out(136) xor RC1(8);
          rc_out(152) <= srb_out(152) xor RC1(9);
          rc_out(168) <= srb_out(168) xor RC1(10);
          rc_out(184) <= srb_out(184) xor RC1(11);
          rc_out(200) <= srb_out(200) xor RC1(12);
          rc_out(216) <= srb_out(216) xor RC1(13);
          rc_out(232) <= srb_out(232) xor RC1(14);
          rc_out(248) <= srb_out(248) xor RC1(15);
          -- looprc: for i in 0 to 15 generate
          --   rc_out(16*i) <= srb_out(16*i) xor RC0(i);
          --   rc_out(16*i + 8) <= srb_out(16*i + 8) xor RC1(i);
          -- end generate looprc;
        process


        begin
          report "inr: 0x" & to_bstring(r_in);
          report "ind: 0x" & to_bstring(d_in);
          report "out0: 0x" & to_bstring(RC0);
          report "out1: 0x" & to_bstring(RC1);
          report "inall: 0x" & to_bstring(srb_out);
          report "outall: 0x" & to_bstring(rc_out);

          wait for 100 ns;
        end process;
end Behavioral;
```

The output i get is **0x2E08CX902FEX10F62X127XCXBX5X8X151XA92XFX2X9XEX2X5XFCAX5X5F5X57F7** for input **0x2E08CD902FE210F626127ECAB75B8F151BA92AF0269EEC2B5BFCA95B5F5457F7**. Never mind the correctness of the lfsr architecture for now at least. RC0 and RC1 are getting some proper values. I've tried the loop..generate, but the results are the same. The code is compiled using VHDL-2008.

Answer (score 1):

'X' means undefined. Usually a symptom of driver conflict, i.e. trying to write to a signal from two places at the same time.

Lets look at your code:

```
rc_out <= (others => '0');
...
rc_out(0) <= srb_out(0) xor RC0(0);
```

Ah there we go. You can do this in a clocked process (and the later occurence takes precedence) but not when using continous asynchronous assignments.

So why isn't there an 'X' every 8 bits?

Well X is about conflicts. No conflict, no X.

```
foo <= '1';
foo <= '1';
```

works just fine.

```
foo <= '0';
foo <= '1';
```

will lead to an 'X'.

So if your XOR results in a '0' it doesn't conflict with the (others => '0') assignment from before.

So either drop the `rc_out <= (others => '0');` or put everything in a proper clocked process.

Comment: "_You can do this in a clocked process_": not only in a clocked process, in any process. "_No conflict, no X_": only because the OP use is a resolved type (`std_logic`). With a much safer (and more reasonable) unresolved type (`std_ulogic`) the OP would not even see `X` in their outputs because they would get an error at analysis or elaboration time. And as the error message would say that multiple drives are forbidden, the OP would not even have asked a question on SO. Lesson: don't use `std_logic` if you don't need multiple drives.

Comment: @Max thanks for the input! I managed to get a proper result, finally.

Comment: @Renaud Pacalet  I've read about the difference of ulogic and logic vectors, but to be honest its the first time seeing a practical example -i indeed get an error when i use the ulogic vector-. Could you elaborate on how i could solve this specific example?

Comment: @PantelosPapado Never assign the same signal from two different processes (concurrent signal assignments are processes), unless the hardware you want at the end is really a wire driven by several sources (e.g., tri-state buffers). Understanding why is easy: imagine a wire connected to the outputs of two different logic gates. What do you think will happen when the two logic gates will disagree? A short-circuit. Something you don't want in your digital circuits. In your case the solution is simple: a process.

Comment: @PantelosPapado Put all assignments to `rc_out`, including `rc_out <= (others => '0');`, in a process with sensitivity list `(srb_out, RC0, RC1)`. And declare all these signals and ports as `std_ulogic` or `std_ulogic_vector` instead of `std_logic` or `std_logic_vector`. This way, next time you make the same mistake the tools will tell you with an explicit error message.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet yup, everything now clicked in place! Thanks for the help :D